# Can't open/browse ASPX pages

Tags: iis, asp.net

I'm having some sort of an IIS config issue. Using IE, I can open HTML files, but cannot open ASPX pages.

I have tried running "aspnet_regiis.exe -i", but it did not correct the issue.

Web extensions show "ASP.NET 1.1.4322" and "ASP.NET 2.0.50727" as both set to "Allowed".

Any ideas?

Comment: is it that the browser displays them as blank pages or do they pop up and you are given the option to save the file locally?

Comment: Is there a MIME type set for ASPX? (Shouldn't be.)

Comment: You don't mention how you are trying to "open" them.... through a browser? Is ASP.NET registered with IIS?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out... sort of. The solution (if you want to call it that) was to uninstall IIS, reinstall IIS, then reinstall Windows 2003 Server SP2. After that, works perfectly.

Comment: I would have tried running `<.net framework directory>\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` first - it sounded like your isapi bindings were messed up.

Comment: I did try that. It made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution you listed, it would make sense that your script mappings were screwy.

To check:  (in IIS manager)

1. Right click on the web site/application and hit "Properties".
2. Click the "Home Directory" tab.
3. Click "Configuration" on the bottom half of the tab.
4. Under the "Mappings" tab, make sure that all of the proper file extensions are mapped to the framework ISAPI dll.

You would need to consult a healthy machine for a complete list of extensions.

Comment: You can also run `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx  Let's you easily switch isapi bindings to a specific version of asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the enable command in the end of the instruction. **Don't forget the "-enable"**. This command was the solution for me and I had the same problem that you have.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 aspnet_regiis.exe -i –enable

The problem is related to IIS, you need to install again the ASP.Net.

> My problem [Solved]
>
> I have a sharepoint site with aspx pages, one day the browser dont open any page, but try to download (open/save dialog) the aspx pages.